# Thinking in react - A calculated field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say I have React component where I render a table data with the following. I also have a table column called **Total** which is a **calculated field**. I know that it can be calculated within the rendered function ex: `price*qty`. This can also be beautified by adding this to a function. But for every row, this function will be called. Looks expensive to me. My question is, is this the right way in React when it comes to performance?

Alternatively, I can call the map function where I calculate the fields beforehand and trigger the render. The problem I see in this approach is that it looks redundant. Every time qty or price value changes I have to calculate manually.

PS: I have the data in structure in an Interface.

In reality, I have a large dataset to render, and calculation can get **lil** complex. What is the best way to approach this?

```
[{"name": "Plumbing", "price": 50, "qty": 3}, 
{"name": "Fixing", "price": 150, "qty": 1}, 
{"name": "Welding", "price": 145, "qty": 9}]
```

Comment: *The problem I see in this approach is that it looks redundant. Every time qty or price value changes I have to calculate manually.* Can you elaborate on this? your qty and val should be part of state. If your qty changes you want a rerender right?

Comment: Yes, the data is already in the state, if the user changes qty or price, the calculated field also should show the correct value

Comment: If `qty` and `price` are state, then `total` being `qty * price` is derived data and doesn't belong in state, it should be computed each render cycle. React has ways to memoize values if performance is an issue, ex: [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo). That being said, don't prematurely optimize. React runs very efficiently out-of-the-box.

Comment: If each row is a component with its own state (including `total`) where `price` and `qty` are passed as props, the calculation is only done when necessary, as far as I can tell. Changing a table row will only re-render that row, and only perform the calculation for that row.

Comment: You may be overcomplicating a simple multiplication. Either if you do it directly or pass the parameters to a function the complexity is usually negligible compared to the complexity of rendering an actual DOM element to display the result. It really all depends on how you are actually using react to do this. Are you using keys correctly to prevent redundant DOM updates for example?

Comment: React will only re render what has changed. If you change one row, it will re calculate that row

Comment: @apokryfos, I always tend to overcomplicate things. Yes, I use the key. Your answer lits the bulb. I forgot that React does the work on virtual dom.

Answer (score 2):

If each row's quantity changes independently of other rows, I would create a component to represent the row, and have the component own the logic for updating its quantity, and therefore its **Total**

This would guarantee that only the row whose quantity changed re-renders, instead of the whole table

```
const Table = () => {
   const rows = [
      {
         name: 'Plumbing',
         price: 50,
         qty: 3,
      },
      {
         name: 'Fixing',
         price: 150,
         qty: 1,
      },
   ]

return (<div>
   {rows.map(r => <TableRow key={r.name} name={r.name} qty={r.qty} price={r.price} />}
   </div>
   );
}


const TableRow = ({name, qty, price}) => {
   const [quantity, setQuantity] = React.useState(qty)

   const handleQtyChanged = (event) => setQuantity(event.target.value)

   return (<p>
      <span>{name}</span>
      <input value={quantity} onChange={(e)=> handleQtyChanged(e)} />
      <span>{quantity * price}</span>
   </p>)
}
```